# Как скрыть public метод в API?

Tags: java

У меня в проекте Java два класса `Class1{}` и `Class2{}`. В `Class2` есть метод `private double pythagoras()`. Я его обозначил как `private`, чтобы он не светился в API. В то же время я хочу его использовать и в другом классе `Class1`. Если я его обозначу всё же как `public`, есть ли способы (какие-то тэги, например) чтобы не показывать его в API? Или какие-то другие способы, оставив `private`, воспользоваться им в другом классе?

Comment: Изучаем: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 6):

1. Если сделаете `private` то он будет невидим везде, кроме самого класса, даже его потомки не будут иметь к нему доступа
2. Если сделаете `protected` то к нему будут иметь доступ все потомки + классы в одном пакете с ним
3. Если сделаете `public` то к нему будут иметь доступ все
4. Если оставите без модификатора, то к нему будут иметь доступ из классов в том же самом пакете

В вашем случае я бы рекомендовал №4

Answer (score 3):

*Вариант для мсье, знающих толк.*

Посредством вызова [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).[`currentThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread%28%29).[`getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29) получаем стек вызовов для данного метода в виде массива из [`StackTraceElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html).  Анализируем массив, проверяя, что текущий метод был вызван из класса, относящегося к вашей библиотеке. Если нет - выкидываем какое-нибудь исключение. Чтобы не добавлять вручную эту проверку в каждый метод, который можно вызывать отлько из API, пользуемся любым [AOP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)-фреймворком ([AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/), [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), самописный велосипед) для того, чтобы неявно воткнуть проверки на права доступа к методу.

Comment: Как вариант, оставить private, но в классе Class1 дергать его через рефлексию.

Comment: @zzashpaupat, вариант неплохой, но в таком случае никто не мешает стороннему коду дёргать метод через рефлексию.

Comment: Ну давайте еще привлечем кастомный загрузчик классов с промежуточной обфускацией :)

Comment: Да-да) А ещё можно включить в процесс сборки этап с кодогенерацией класса, проверяющего доступ, и вшить в него имена всех классов, присутствующих в библиотеке. И подписать библиотеку, чтобы нехорошие личности не подменили класс.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть вам подойдёт **protected** см. [Java/Видимость](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Скорее, как указали ниже, package-private подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день! Попробуйте положить `Class1{}` и `Class2{}` в один пакет, и у метода `double pythagoras()` сделайте модификатор доступа как **default** (заместо private, слово default писать не надо). Тогда этот метод будет виден всем в данном пакете, но не будет виден извне

Будет так

```
package asd;

public class Class2{
 double pythagoras(){...}
 ...
}

package asd;

public class Class1{
 public void someMethod() {
   Class2 c = new Class2();
   double res = c.pythagoras(); // спокойно можно вызывать
   ...
 }
}
```